# php mail list improvements

Tags: php, list, email

I have a database with subscribers to a mailing list.

I'm using a php script to fetch email addresses from the database and then send an email to each address.
This was working fine until the number of subscribers grew to large.

Now, the script times out and some subscribers report that they are getting more than one email, some subscribers does not get an email at all.

I think the problem might be that the script takes to long to execute because of to many rows returned from the database (163 subscribers), but I'm note sure. I don't have access to the php.ini file (the server is ashared platform)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve my script? How can I make sure that every subscriber gets an email and is there a way to avoid duplicates?

```
<?php

//Database connection script
include_once 'inc/dbconnect.php';


$message='Test message';


    $query="SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE type=1";
    $res1=mysqli_query($dbh, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

    while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)){ 

        $from='myname@mydomain.se';
        $fromname='My name';
        $to=$user['email'];
        $subject='Message subject';
        $header='From: myname@mydomain.se
Reply-To: myname@mydomain.se
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-mailer: PHP '.phpversion();   


        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)){
            print 'Mail sent to '.$to.'<br>';
        }
        else{
        print 'Could not send mail to '.$to.'<br>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at _set\_time\_limit( seconds )_. Works only if the server is not running in safe mode. An alternative could be to split up the selection (INDEX, OFFSET) in portions.

Comment: Add each email address to bcc so that they cant see each others email but in that way u can send 1 mail to 10 people

Answer (score 0):

To optimise query, always use comma separated fieldname rather than using *.

In your case to avoid duplicates use below query.

$query="SELECT DISTINCT(email) FROM subscribers WHERE type=1";  // this will fetch only distinct email.

There are possibility of page getting time out as well.
You can always increase maximum execution time.

There are 3 ways to do so.

With htaccess
php_value max_execution_time 300

Change dynamically with PHP
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

Change in php.ini // for this you need to contact server person to help you if you dont have direct access to it.
max_execution_time = 120

Answer (score 0):

Sending email to everyone one by one is bad practice. It'll slow down your system.Why don't you use any library? There is one awesome library available in market called Swift Mailer. Just use it. It'll really help you.

> Swift Mailer integrates into any web app written in PHP 5, offering a
>   flexible and elegant object-oriented approach to sending emails with a
>   multitude of features.

Home URL : http://swiftmailer.org/

Github : https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer

It'll allows you to send multiple emails in one shot by providing array of multiple recipients.

Answer (score 0):

PHP typically runs in a request/response environment. Each response from the server has a run time limit to avoid a single response overloading the server. As you've said this is probably your problem. If it isn't now, it is likely to become an issue as the number of users increases.

If you can't change the execution time limit (likely on a shared server) then to deal with this one issue I would-

1. Measure the execution time of your script for various size batches of users.
2. Choose a "batch size" that completes in comfortably below the time limit.
3. Break your mail job into chunks / batches of that size.

The tricky part is handing-off the state of where you've got to to the next cycle of the batch process. You could look into either writing a "batch process cursor position" into the database, or just have your email batch page redirect to itself before exiting with a "start from here" parameter in the URL.

Longer term you might need to look into having a general-purpose batch queue facility to handle long running jobs. That might need access to cron on the server though, assuming you are running on a Linux/Unix box.